# Reliable object not resizing java JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I'm trying to make a file view(JScrollPane) resizable for an ide, but when I try to resize it, It wont update unless I resize the window.
I try looking it up but I could not find anything usefull.
If you help me on this thank you so much.

Take a look fore yourself

```java
public MainWindow(String title) {
        
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.setResizable(true);
        this.setSize(windowSize);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        // ....

        JPanel fileView = new JPanel();
        fileView.setBackground(Color.WHITE.darker());

        JScrollPane fileScrollView = new JScrollPane(fileView);
        fileScrollView.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 0));

        fileScrollView.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener() {
            private int offset = 0;
            private boolean start = false;

            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                int mouseX = e.getX() ;
                int left = fileScrollView.getX() + fileScrollView.getWidth();
                boolean resize = setCursor(left, mouseX);

                if (start) {
                    offset = left - mouseX;
                }

                if (resize) {
                    LOGGER.logInfo("OFFSET: " + offset);
                    fileScrollView.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(mouseX + offset, fileScrollView.getHeight()));

                    repaint();
                    doLayout();
                }
                start = false;
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                start = true;
                setCursor(fileScrollView.getX() + fileScrollView.getWidth(), e.getX());
            }

            public boolean setCursor(int right, int mx) {
                if (mx > right - 20 && mx < right){
                    fileScrollView.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.E_RESIZE_CURSOR));
                    return true;
                } else {
                    fileScrollView.setCursor(Cursor.getDefaultCursor());
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });



        this.add(fileScrollView, BorderLayout.WEST);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

> It wont update unless I resize the window.

```
repaint();
doLayout();
```

First of all, the order of the statements is wrong. You should not attempt to repaint something if you haven't redone the layout.

However, you should not invoke doLayout() directly. Instead, you can use:

```
fileScrollView.revalidate();
fileScrollView.repaint(); // sometimes needed
```

The `revalidate()` will invoke the layout manager. Sometime repaint() is also needed to make sure the panel is repainted.

Comment: I;m not trying to update the fileScrollView I'm trying to update the MainWindow when fileScrollView is resize the All the other objects will line up with the layout

Comment: You are changing a property of a component which may or may not change the size of the component. Therefore, you need to revalidate() the component. The revalidate logic will invoke the layout manager of the parent container. If you need more help, then post a proper [mre] with your question.